# Safari won't use text-align justify using @font-face

Tags: css, safari, font-face

I'm using an @font-face declaration for all of my content text. This looks gorgeous in most browsers. However, in Safari the "text-align: justify"-property won't work! Right, left and center work fine, but the combination of @font-face and justify results in left-aligned text.

The problem seems to exist only in Safari. Chrome is working fine.

Comment: Yep it doesn't work. I can't access the Safari bug tracker because I'm not an Apple developer, but there may be a bug filed in there somewhere. Hard to provide an answer as you're not asking a question :)

Comment: I think you just pretty much answered my question. I'd vote for it.

Comment: Okay, added as an answer :) Sorry I couldn't be more help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep it doesn't work. I can't access the Safari bug tracker because I'm not an Apple developer, but there may be a bug filed in there somewhere. If there isn't then I'd suggest filing one.